# Javascript convention when clashing with a reserved word

Tags: javascript, coding-style, naming-conventions

In python, when a variable name clashes with a reserved word (like in `class`, `in`, `default`, etcetera), the PEP8 convention states that a trailing underscore should be used (`class_`, `in_`, `default_`).

What is the most shared javascript convention for the same case?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there isn't one. Basically you just avoid using reserved words. For `class`, for instance, I've seen: `Class`, `cls`, `klazz`, `clazz`, and `className`. As a further example, when doing the mappings of attributes to properties on DOM elements (which are ovewhelmingly used from JavaScript), the W3C folks went with `className` (for `class`), `htmlFor` (for `for`), `cssFloat` (for `float`), and such. I've never seen someone use a trailing `_`. (A *leading* `_`, on the other hand, is quite common — people use it for properties of objects they want people to consider private.)

When doing a *property*, technically you don't have to worry about it, because technically property names can be reserved words according to the specification, as the parser has enough context to know that the property name isn't something else. (That doesn't mean all *implementations* will get it right, and I don't recommend it.) This is because property names are just required to be what the spec calls *IdentifierName*, not *Identifier*. (*Identifier* is literally ["*IdentifierName* but not *ReservedWord*"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6)).

For those who prefer not to risk it with property names, the common way to do it is to use quotes:

```
var obj = { "class": "is perfectly fine" };

// Access
console.log(obj["class"]);
```

Comment: Just a side-note: I don't know exactly which keywords require the bracket notation, but `var foo = {class: 'bar', function: 'zar'}; console.log(foo.class); console.log(foo.function);` work fine in chrome

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: It's a matter of context. It's best to stay away from [reserved words](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1), but in certain contexts (such as your example, the *property name* portion of an object initialiser), you can get away with it. In the spec, the distinction is held by having *IdentifierName* where it has enough context not to care about conflicts, and *Identifier* where it doesn't. An [*Identifier* is an *IdentifierName* that isn't a *ReservedWord*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6). I just prefer not to trip myself up. :-)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Of course, that makes my example in the answer pretty lame. :-) So I've updated.

Comment: Well of course, I completely agree, and if I were to use reserved words as property names, I'd play it safe, too. I was just being a pedantic jerk ;)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Pedantic, possibly, certainly not a jerk. :-)